# Possessive nouns, the apostrophe, and no 'S'

Tags: apostrophe

I was watching an episode of Last Week Tonight With John Oliver. It's an American show hosted by an Englishman. 
He displayed a paragraph of text during the show which read, "The Bad Boys Club' T-shirt."
I am confused. The club is called The Bad Boys Club so I figure it's irrelevant that there's not an apostrophe in or after the word Boys. But please can someone explain the lack of an S after the word Club?

Comment: Unclear.  Are you asking about the apostrophe you have shown following "Club"?

Comment: It looks OK to me. You are right that no genitive marking is required on "boys", and likewise it is not required on "Club" either.

Comment: Yes, Hot Locks. I was expecting 's rather than just '

Comment: You need either "The Bad Boys Club T-shirt" or "The Bad Boys Club's T-shirt". They have slightly different usages which sites such as English Language Learners will happily explain. "The Bad Boys Club' T-shirt" is as wrong as "my' T-shirt" or "your' example" or "his' mistake."

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the punctuation.

First of all, using *'* and not *'s* is typically only done when there is a possessive of a *plural* subject:

> The two cars' engines.
>   The many Christmas trees' lights.

(In the past, it used to be a stylistic convention to put only a *'* after a *singular* subject that ended in *s*. Although that is still done by some people, the convention has shifted away from that recently.)

The subject in question here seems to be **The Bad Boys Club**.

Despite having the plural **boys** as part of its name, it is a singular **club**.

---

There are two ways of interpreting this:

> 1. The Bad Boys Club's T-shirt.

Here, it's a single T-shirt that is owned by the club.

> 2. The Bad Boys Club T-shirt.

Here, it's a *type* of T-shirt that represents The Bad Boys Club. (The club name acts adjectivally.)

This is similar to wearing a *Nike* shoe rather than a *Nike's* shoe.

---

But in whichever interpretation, the sole apostrophe after **Club** isn't correct.

Comment: By  focusing on grammatical number (plurality) instead of on sound laws governing inflectional morphology, you lose sight of what actually matters for any of these: *these children’s toys, those mice’s droppings, some women’s husbands, those geese’s nests, all phenomena’s explanations, these corpora’s common origin, those nuclei’s organelles, this species’ name, these species’ names*. The actual rules aren’t about the number, because if they were, we would not say or write any of those that way. But we do.

Comment: @tchrist Sound laws aren’t really what matter either, though. The plural morpheme written ⟨s⟩ never takes ⟨s⟩ as part of its possessive marker, only the bare apostrophe, which you might attribute to their lack of any phonetic representation of the possessive, which is of course sound law–based. But singular nouns ending in ⟨s⟩ which can optionally take ⟨’⟩ or ⟨’s⟩ as their possessive marker regardless of pronunciation (like _Socrates’/Socrates’s_) are not explainable by sound laws, only by orthographic convention.

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question. From the 17th edition of the *CMS*:

> Although terms denoting group ownership or participation sometimes
>   appear without an apostrophe (i.e., as an attributive rather than a
>   possessive noun), Chicago dispenses with the apostrophe only in proper
>   names (often corporate names) that do not officially include one. In a
>   few established cases, a singular noun can be used attributively; if
>   in doubt, choose the plural possessive. (Irregular plurals such as
>   *children* and *women* must always be in the possessive.)
>
> *children’s rights (or child rights)*
>
> *farmers’ market*
>
> *women’s soccer team*
>
> *boys’ clubs*
>
> *veterans’ organizations*
>
> *players’ unions*
>
> *taxpayers’ associations (or taxpayer associations)*
>
> *consumers’ group (or consumer group)*
>
> **but**
>
> *Publishers Weekly*
>
> *Diners Club*
>
> *Department of Veterans Affairs*
>
> In some cases, the distinction between attributive and possessive is subtle. Of the following two examples, only the first connotes actual possession.
>
> *the Lakers’ game plan (the team’s game plan)*
>
> **but**
>
> *the Lakers game (the game featuring the team)*
>
> When in doubt, opt for the possessive.

Basically, there should have been an *s* after the apostrophe.

See this as well:

> The possessive of most *singular* nouns is formed by adding an apostrophe and an *s*. The possessive of *plural* nouns (except for a few irregular plurals, like *children*, that do not end in *s*) is formed by adding an apostrophe only.
>
> *the horse’s mouth*
>
> *a bass’s stripes*
>
> *puppies’ paws*
>
> *children’s literature*
>
> *a herd of sheep’s mysterious disappearance*

*Chicago* does provide a few exceptions to these principles.